# Python - Selenium Webdriver and reCAPTCHA

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am developing a login validator in Python 3 using selenium webdriver. I have a CSV with 10 username and passwords that the program will validate. Now, the website on which I have to validate is protected by reCAPTCHA. So after two or three entries, I am considered a bot and asked to "prove I am human". I am using Chrome browser.

Can someone suggest me ways of performing this task smoothly. Are there other options compared to selenium webdriver?

Comment: cross-posted: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/44347/python-selenium-webdriver-and-recaptcha

Answer (score 1):

One of reCAPTCHA's purposes for existing is to prevent Selenium and similar programs from doing exactly what you're trying to do. My best advice would be to test against a development instance of your website without the reCAPTCHA protection feature enabled.